# while true for all threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#define nThreads 5

pthread_mutex_t lock;
void *start(void *param) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
while (true)
{

   //do certain things , mutex to avoid critical section problem
   int * number = (int *) param;
    cout<<*number;
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

}
int main() 
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    pthread_t tid[nThreads];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, start, (void *) &i);
    for(i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    return 0;
}
```

my question is whether all the threads are looping infinitely or only the first thread is looping. and if only one thread is looping, how to make all threads loop infinitely and should mutex be inside the while loop or outside :S !!

thanks in advance.

Comment: One thread, the first one to get the mutex, will loop. The others will block waiting for the mutex. The remaining questions are impossible to answer without more specific requirements.

Comment: It probably helps to understand that *mutex* is short for *mutually exclusive*, meaning that at any given time at most one thread can *own* a mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mutex is outside the loop as you've shown, then only one thread can enter that loop.  If that loop runs forever (as `while (true)` will do if there's no `break` statement inside), then only one thread will actually get to loop and the rest will be locked out.

Move the mutex around just the code that you need to protect.  If you want all the threads looping in parallel, taking turns accessing a common structure, move the mutex inside the loop.

Comment: while (true)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
   //do certain things , mutex to avoid critical section problem
   int * number = (int *) param;
    cout<<*number;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
if it's like this, the others threads are looping infinitely and in parallel... number would still be 0 though right ?? ... I mean, threads can't print in parallel.. so I won't be able to see 0000000000012233333444222 something like this ..!

Comment: The threads will take turns (probably somewhat randomly).  On each iteration of the loop, all the threads will try to take the lock, but only one thread succeeds at a time.  When that thread releases the lock, some thread (either the same thread or another thread) will win taking it the next time.  If I understood correctly, where each thread prints its own number, you could get something like 0000000000012233333444222.

Answer (score 0):

In this case only 1 thread is in loop , also **this will be the first thread to enter** since that will never unlock mutex no other thread will enter ie, all other thread will wait indefinitely. I think what you want is this:

```
while (true)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
   //do certain things , mutex to avoid critical section problem
   int * number = (int *) param;
    cout<<*number;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```